# Subscribing to COM events in managed COM assembly from C#

Tags: c#, events, com, regfreecom

I have a .NET 3.5 application, and need to use .NET 4 for a certain part of it. I have thus exposed the .NET 4 part as a registration free COM assembly.

In a .NET 3.5 assembly, I have the following code, which works fine:

```
Type comClassType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("A.ProgID");
object comObject = Activator.CreateInstance(comClassType);
var managedObj = (IManagedInterface)comObject;
managedObj.MyMethod(); // call .NET 4 method from .NET 3.5
```

The declaration of IManagedInterface is as follows:

```
[Guid("ED915810-1B19-4357-9FD4-564CFC0AFAFF")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IManagedInterface
{
    void MyMethod();
    ...
}
```

I also have an events interface, declared like this:

```
[Guid("D3633346-EB8B-4F62-A806-3C393D40F694")]
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface IMyComEvents
{
    void MyEvent()
}
```

This is, as far as I can tell, according to this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd8bf0x3.aspx

My .NET 4 COM class is as follows:

```
[Guid("7BA49B2D-A359-4B70-BEB1-2A61EA63EFA4")]
[ComVisible(true)]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IMyComEvents))]
public class ManagedComWrapper : IManagedInterface
{
    ...
}
```

The question then is: how can I, in the .NET 3.5 client shown at the top, subscribe to/handle the events from IMyComEvents?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd8bf0x3.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, that link is mentioned in my question. Is there some info there that I have missed?

Comment: Maybe you were looking for this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811645